# Mongo shell and result from code returns different results

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm new to mongodb and go and was trying to follow an example, but can't check for data in mongo shell since they return different results

my go code

```
    package main

    import (
        "context"
        "fmt"
        "log"

        "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
        "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
        "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    )

    //Trainer You will be using this Trainer type later in the program
    type Trainer struct {
        Name string
        Age  int
        City string
    }

    func main() {
        // Set client options
        clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017")

        // Connect to MongoDB
        client, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), clientOptions)

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        // Check the connection
        err = client.Ping(context.TODO(), nil)

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        fmt.Println("Connected to MongoDB!")

        collection := client.Database("db_test").Collection("trainers")

        ash := Trainer{"Ash", 10, "Pallet Town"}
        misty := Trainer{"Misty", 10, "Cerulean City"}
        brock := Trainer{"Brock", 15, "Pewter City"}

        trainers := []interface{}{ash, misty, brock}

        insertResult, err := collection.InsertMany(context.TODO(), trainers)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        fmt.Println("Inserted a single document: ", insertResult.InsertedIDs)

        result, err := collection.Find(context.TODO(), bson.D{}, options.Find())

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println("Find Failed.")

        for result.Next(context.TODO()) {
            var singleRow Trainer
            err := result.Decode(&singleRow)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }

            fmt.Println(singleRow.Name, "+", singleRow.Age)
        }

        fmt.Println("Find finished")

        err = client.Disconnect(context.TODO())

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println("Connection to MongoDB closed.")

    }
```

this returns

```
    Connected to MongoDB!
    Inserted a single document:  [ObjectID("5da929e60a2ef8952d92ce8c") ObjectID("5da929e60a2ef8952d92ce8d") ObjectID("5da929e60a2ef8952d92ce8e")]
    Find Failed.
    Ash + 10
    Misty + 10
    Brock + 15
    Find finished
    Connection to MongoDB closed.
```

the mongo shell

[image: 1]

Is it because the mongo shell and my go code connect to different clusters or something?
Also I've tried using compass and it shows a different result than the mongo shell too. How do i know the shell is working properly?
My path environment was set to "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin" so i dont think there's a problem with that

Comment: When you use the shell, unless you explicitly state the database you want to use at the command line, you „are“ in the default database, which is `test`. You do your operations in a database named `db_test`. Issue a `use db_test` in the shell and your query should work.

Comment: i did, as you can see in the powershell terminal. Still it doesnt work

Comment: very strange, I just executed your code, with a mongo in docker, and I can see all 3  documents in it. Btw, this is the tutorial, right? https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-go-driver-tutorial

Comment: In your mongodb, if you run "show dbs" and "show collections" does it return at least the collection or db there? Is your go script running locally in the same machine as the mongodb, right?

Comment: Yes, my go script runs locally in the same computer as the mongodb

Answer (score 1):

Try running your Go code, after replacing the following line

```
clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017")
```

with this

```
clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb")
```

Comment: it returns an error : "error parsing uri: must have a / before the query ?"

Comment: Can you check it again?I've edited the line and added a " /"  before the "?"

Comment: Go code works normally, but the mongo shell still doesnt show any records. Even "show collections" command doesnt return anything